# elementary OS is not fullscreen

Tags: display

I installed elementary OS 0.3.1 yesterday. 
I'm not getting the fullscreen. 
How can I get elementary OS to display fullscreen and also then use the actual full screen and not the given resolution? 
The rest is now black.

Comment: OP are you using a virtual machine or is this a real install?

Comment: Hi Daniel, this is the real install. My computer is a Dell Inspiron 5000 that came with Ubuntu 14.04 that was in fullscreen. Then I formatted the Hard Drive and then installed Freya. I am really enjoying the OS but I would like to it to appear in the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

adjust the resolution in settings, it's found at **displays** option when you click the gear icon, you should set it to maximum value available.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell you guys that I've tried this already. It didnt work

Comment: What do you mean by "It didn't work"? Was your actual resolution listed? Were you able to select it? What happened next?

Comment: I selected my actual resolution and still the computer doesn't appear in fullscreen.